# Why hash set allows adding duplicate object?

Tags: java, hashset

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee("abc",10.0);
        Employee e3 = new Employee("abc",10.0);

        HashSet<Employee> hs = new HashSet<Employee>();
        hs.add(e1);
        hs.add(e3);

        System.out.println("size of hs : "+hs.size());

        Object [] aa = hs.toArray();

        for(int i=0;i<aa.length;i++){

            Object ii = aa[i];
            System.out.println("ii "+(i+1)+"="+ii.toString());
        }

        Iterator it = hs.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Employee e4 = (Employee) it.next();
            System.out.println("e4 ="+e4);
            System.out.println("111="+it.next());
        }

        Enumeration e5 = new Vector(hs).elements();
        while(e5.hasMoreElements()){
            Employee e6 = (Employee) e5.nextElement();
            System.out.println("e6 ="+e6);
        }

    }

}

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private Double salary;

    public Employee(String name, Double salary){
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }

    public void getNameSal() throws NullPointerException{
        System.out.println(this.name +""+this.salary);
    }

}
```

looking at above code, I have created one hash set which accepts object of `Employee` class.
I have created two objects of `Employee` class with same values and added in hash set.
But when I print size of hash set it shows 2.
And also when iterate by three ways by converting it into array, `Iterator` and `Enumerator` then it displays both the values which are duplicate.
But when I try to print using `it.next()` it prints only single value.
Why is it so?

```
Output:
size of hs : 2
ii 1=Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
ii 2=Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
e4 =Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
111=Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
e6 =Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
e6 =Employee [name=abc, salary=10.0]
```

Comment: Ask yourself a question: how does the set know when two Employee are equal or not? Read the javadoc of Set. (and HashSet)

Comment: You are not overriding equals and hashcode in the employee class and you are calling iterator.next() twice, once when you initialize your variable and once when you print it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't implement equals() and hashCode() for your Employee class, HashSet uses the default equals implementation, i.e. an object is only equal to itself. Therefore, your two Employee objects are not equal, and thus the second object doesn't overwrite the first.
So, the solution is to implement equals() and hashCode() on your Employee class and check that all fields are equal that are part of your definition of two Employees being equal.

You only see one employee printed, because you have a bug in your code: you call next() twice per iteration of your first while loop.

Comment: This answer is not complete if it doesn't talk about hashCode().

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` is using `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the objects behind the hood.

Since you do not override these methods for your `Employee` class, the `HashSet` can only see that two Employees are equal if they share the same instance.

To resolve your issue, you need to override `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `Employee` class.

Comment: **HashSet** uses hashCode and equals(). Not all Set implementations do. Set doesn't use anything: it's an interface.